# How to show div in using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function Myfunction1() {

var a = document.getElementById("signup");
    var b = document.getElementById("loginpage1");

    if (a.style.display === "none") {
        a.style.display = "block";
        b.style.display = "none";

    } else {

        b.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: When im using this script.. it displays the div for a second & return.

Comment: It means `Myfunction1` is called twice. Create a [MCVE](stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: That comment should be *in the question*: the behaviour you are seeing is key information.

Comment: Yes @Richard I'm sorry i forget to post it in question bar.

Comment: You can edit your question to add it.

Answer (score 0):

this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/s6drLnyf/) will help you.

```
function Myfunction1() {

var a = document.getElementById("signup");
var b = document.getElementById("loginpage1");

if (a.style.display === "none") {
    a.style.display = "block";
    b.style.display = "none";

} else {
    a.style.display = "none";
    b.style.display = "block";
}
```

}

Comment: It's still the same, I really don't getting it.

Answer (score 0):

Always `a.style.display === "none"` will not work when you hide by CSS selector specially from external stylesheet file. To overcome this situation please try following way:

```
function Myfunction1() {

var a = document.getElementById("signup");
var b = document.getElementById("loginpage1");

if (a.offsetParent === null) {
    a.style.display = "block";
    b.style.display = "none";

} else {
    a.style.display = "none";
    b.style.display = "block";
}
}
```

Comment: Still returning to login Div.